# Javascript functional programming - Should I write functions that force currying, or use _.curry when calling instead?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, currying

Example:

Version 1:

```
const foo = (arg1) => {
  return (arg2) => {
    return (arg3) => {
      return arg1 + arg2 + arg3;
    }
  }
}
// called as part of a pipe: 
const result = pipe(bar, foo(arg1)(arg2), baz);
```

Version 2:

```
const foo = (arg1, arg2, arg3) => {
  return arg1 + arg2 + arg3;
}

// called as part of a pipe: 
const result = pipe(bar, _curry(foo)(arg1)(arg2), baz);
```

The method implementation is much cleaner and more elegant in Version 2, however the call is a little uglier. Since method calls (hopefully) appear in more than one place in the codebase, I'm trying to decide which version has less drawbacks.

I hope I don't need to explain why I want to achieve using curried functions and passing single arguments. Please approach the question from a pro-functional programming standpoint.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"I hope I don't need to explain why"_ - you most likely will because there will be someone who will ask. Let me be the first one, why do you want to do this? What are you trying to achieve? Why make it complicated? The time spent to ask and ponder over this could have been used to do other things by going the simpler route.

Comment: This is opinion-based. There is no rule. Just do what you see fit.

Comment: Do whichever one seems more readable in your case, there's no one size fits all

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer https://medium.com/javascript-scene/the-rise-and-fall-and-rise-of-functional-programming-composable-software-c2d91b424c8c#.awkkrgdju

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object of the function in case you don't know how many arguments there could be like this:

```js
function foo() {
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
    sum += arguments[i];
  return sum;
}

console.log(foo());
console.log(foo(1, 2, 3));
console.log(foo(5, 6, 3, 7, 1, 10));
```

And if you want a currying that is independent of the number of arguments without forcing it using `_.curry`, then use this:

```js
function foo(a) {
  var sum = 0;
  var _ = function(a) {
    if(a === undefined)
      return sum;
    else {
      sum += a;
      return _;
    }
  }
  return _(a);
}

console.log(foo());
console.log(foo(1)(2)());
console.log(foo(1)(2)(7)(10)(5)());
```

Comment: So old school. Use the rest operator to pass arguments if unknown the number of arguments expected is.  `function(x,y,...args)` destructured so your function code is more readable `function(,...[a,b,c])`  also call with spread operator `myFunc(...argArray)`